# TypeScript type alias to pick values of an object matching a set of arbitratry keys that may or may not exist in the object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following:

```
type X = {foo: string};
type Y = {foo: number};
type Z = {foo: string, bar: number};
type W = {bar: string};
type Q = {baz: string};

type ValueOf<T, K> = ...
```

I want to create the `ValueOf` type that for a union of arbitrary string keys - which may or may not be part of a target object - matches any values in the target object that *do* correspond to any of those keys.

```
ValueOf<X, 'foo' | 'bar'> -> should give 'string'
ValueOf<Y, 'foo' | 'bar'> -> should give 'number'
ValueOf<Z, 'foo' | 'bar'> -> should give 'string' | 'number'
ValueOf<W, 'foo' | 'bar'> -> should give 'string'
ValueOf<Q, 'foo' | 'bar'> -> should give 'unknown'
```

I've tried creating `ValueOf` like this:

```
type ValueOf<T, K extends keyof any> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : unknown;
```

However, this doesn't work, because `'foo' | 'bar'` does not extend `keyof X` since `X` does not have *both* `foo` and `bar` as keys, so the result is `unknown`. What I need is a type that picks any matching keys from the target object and ignores the rest. Only if *no* keys match, the result should be `unknown`.

Is this possible?

The closest I've got is to split the union type into multiple arguments, but that does not become at all flexible, obviously:

```
type ValueOf<T, K1 extends keyof any, K2 extends keyof any, K3 extends keyof any> = 
  K1 extends keyof T ? T[K1] : 
    K2 extends keyof T ? T[K2] : 
      K3 extends keyof T ? T[K3] : 
        unknown;
```

Here you must always supply exactly three alternate key names. One could use default types of `never` or `any` for `K1, K2, K3`, but makes it impossible to default to `unknown`, so this is far from useful in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)

> Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.

```
type SelectExistingKeysOf<T, K extends String> = K extends keyof T  
  ? T[K] 
  : never;

type ValueOf<T, K extends String> = SelectExistingKeysOf<T, K> extends never 
  ? unknown 
  : SelectExistingKeysOf<T, K>;
 
type test1 = ValueOf<X, 'foo' | 'bar'>;     // string
type test2 = ValueOf<X, 'foo'>;             // string
type test3 = ValueOf<X, 'bar'>;             // unknown
type test4 = ValueOf<Z, 'foo' | 'bar'>;     // string | number
```